# How would I separate thousands with space in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, custom-formatting

Assume I have the following decimal number that I have to format so that every thousand should be separated with a space:

```
 897.11 to 897.11
 1897.11 to 1 897.11
 12897.11 to 12 897.11
 123897.11 to 123 897.11
```

I have tried Decimal.ToString("0 000.00"). Although this works pretty well when the number is 1897.11. But when it's 897.11 I get 0 897.11.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Pass in a custom [`NumberFormatInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.aspx) with a custom [`NumberGroupSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator.aspx), and use the [`#,#` format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx#SpecifierTh) to tell it to do number groups. This example uses the invariant culture's number format as its basis.

```
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
string formatted = 1234897.11m.ToString("#,0.00", nfi); // "1 234 897.11"
```

Comment: +1 , I have edited this answer to handle zero values properly - the previous format string "#,#.00" caused zero to be represented as ".00" now it is "0.00"

Answer (score 23):

You need a custom number format provider where you change the character yourself:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        decimal d = 2000000;

        var f = new NumberFormatInfo {NumberGroupSeparator = " "};

        var s = d.ToString("n", f); // 2 000 000.00
    }
```

Here I also specify to format it as a number (using `"n"`), please see this link for other formatting options:

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

In this case, it won't work if you format as a currency or a percentage, because as you may already note the `NumberFormatInfo` has separate properties for those.

The current culture format info can be found on `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat`.

Answer (score 13):

try this

```
int testNumber = 134566548;
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N}", testNumber));
```

You will received :
134 566 548,00

Don't forget your culture.

Answer (score 11):

with a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx), but use '#' not '0's  a 0 is a mandatory token it will be there no matter how long the number is,  the pound sign (#) is optional token, it will only be used for digits actually in the number.

```
  Decimal.ToString("# ###.00")
```

NOTE.  I'll leave this here, but @Tim S' answer is a better one.

When I try this I see it only generates the first separator... I guess the separator only works for commas and periods here.  As a workaround (up to the maximum size number you expect), try this instead.

```
  Decimal.ToString("# ### ### ### ###.00")
```

Comment: For `1234897.11` this results in `1234 897.11` (i.e. it only separates the first group).

Comment: @Tim,  that sounds like a bug in the framework code.  see my edit

Comment: @Tin S answer is better than mine.  Did not know `NumberFormatInfo` existed

Comment: I feel like this one is more obvious at a glance what it is doing.

Comment: for 0.1 it returns ".1". For fix it try Decimal.ToString("# ##0.00") and you may need .Trim()

Answer (score 5):

Sweden Use thousand separator as Space(" ") and Decimal point separator as Comma(,). We can achieve this in the following way.

```
decimal myNumbber = 5878.476M;
var swedishCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");           
swedishCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
swedishCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
var s = myNumbber.ToString("#,###.00", swedishCulture);
```

Which gives the output

```
"5 878,48"
```

Comment: Question, why would you need to specify the separator values?  Aren't these already defined in the CultureInfo's NumberFormatInfo property?

Answer (score 4):

Norwegian locale uses spaces as a separator, so if you were designing a website or application specifically for Norwegians, then you could use:

```
(123897.11).ToString("n",new CultureInfo("nb-NO"))
```

Which results in

```
"123 897,11"
```

Obviously, if you're not writing an application for the Norwegian market, then this would be a silly solution.

Comment: I used something like `(123897.11).ToString("n4",new CultureInfo("nb-NO"))` for 4 decimal places. Tks.

Answer (score 0):

```
double salaire = 0;
string salaire_s = "0";

private void txtSalaire_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSalaire.Text = FormatMontant(salaire_s);
    txtSalaire.Select(txtSalaire.Text.Length, 0);
}

private void txtSalaire_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    salaire = ClassUtility.AllowNumbersFormatDecimal(e, salaire_s);
    salaire_s = salaire.ToString();
}

public static string FormatMontant(string montant_string)
{
    double montant = 0;
    if (montant_string.Equals(""))
    {
        montant_string = "0";
    }
    montant = Convert.ToDouble(montant_string);
    return String.Format("{0:n0}", montant);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?