# How to format a number into comma only without decimal point but already round into non decimal point using C#

Tags: c#

I want format this ActualSize property into Non Decimal point but have a comma separated. Eg. I have the value 1000.65 convert it into 1,001 and not 1,000

Example:

```
public class Price 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // I want format this ActualSize property into Non Decimal point but have a comma separated. Eg. I have the value 1000.65 convert it into 1,001 and not 1,000 
    public long? ActualSize { get; set; }
}

public List<Product> ListProduct()
{
    List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();

    listProducts.Add(new Product {Id = "1", Name = "Product 1" ActualSize = 1000.65 });
    listProducts.Add(new Product {Id = "2", Name = "Product 2", ActualSize = 2443.76 });
    return listProducts;
}
```

Comment: how can you store float point to `long?` ?

Comment: Does this work for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965472/1193647

Comment: I have noticed few things, your class name is `Price` but you are created ` List<Product>` with that,  `ActualSize` is of type `long?` and you are assiging a decimal value to it. why do you need a `long` there?

Comment: Yes, your right. As the example above I need to retrieve and parse the value into non decimal point.

Comment: could you please take a look into the updates in my post?

Comment: see for this is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150774/why-linq-query-and-extension-dont-support-conversion-or-rounding-numbers

Answer (score 0):

Hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
string formatedOp = 2319000.6.ToString("#,##,##"); // 2,319,001
```

Here is a [working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QijjIq).

But still I don't get what you are going to deal with `long?` if this for any specific reason means please include the reason so that I can update my answer. anyway you cannot store values with commas in long but you can print them with commas as like what I did in the above example.

Updates as per modified question: So your input contains some double values and you want them as in the specified format. I can suggest an option for this don't know whether it help you or not. anyway you can make a try:

Make the following changes in the properties:
 - change `long?` to `double?` as your input is double.
 - Include a readonly string property in the class which returns the specific string.
 - Which will be updated when you set the double value.
In short the class will looks like the following after applying the following changes:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private string _ActualSizeStr;
    private double? _ActualSize;

    public string ActualSizeStr
    {
        get { return _ActualSizeStr; }
    }

    public double? ActualSize
    {
        get { return _ActualSize; }
        set
        {
            _ActualSize = value;
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                _ActualSizeStr = value.Value.ToString("#,##,##");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So when you assign a value(let it be `2319000.6`) for `ActualSize` the `_ActualSizeStr` will be updated with the required value(`2,319,001`) so that when you retrieve or use those values make use of `ActualSizeStr` instead for `ActualSize`.

Comment: Thank you, but how to apply it in property? Honestly, I use it in LINQ which is not supported.

Comment: Edit your question and then add the actual code, that would help us to give more useful suggestions

Comment: I updated the question the code. Please see. thank you.

Comment: Thank you @un-lucky. One more thing how to do conversion in LINQ?

Comment: I don't get what you meant by `conversion in LINQ` , sounds like a different question, if so ask it as a separate question

Comment: see for this is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150774/why-linq-query-and-extension-dont-support-conversion-or-rounding-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Format() like this:

`string areaSize = String.Format("{0:n0}", AreaSize);`

Comment: Thank you, but how to apply it in property? Honestly, I use it in LINQ which is not supported.

Comment: @StephenShuane It is, it will just require 1 additional step. First you "get" everything as string with `ToList()` and then in next step you can use this Format function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the string in using a .ToString overload.

If you need the spaces you need a custom format string, as there is nothing [built into .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) that does exactly what you have specified.

I actually for some reason thought there was a comma format built into .NET but I don't see it, if you don't need the spaces the following works:

```
1234897.11m.ToString("{0,0}}");
```

However if you do need the spaces it is much more a pain (thank you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527847/how-would-i-separate-thousands-with-space-in-c-sharp) for the answer).

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
var nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.Clone();
nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ,";
1234897.11m.ToString("#,0", nfi);
```

I just noticed you want it inside your property:

```
public string FormatedAreaSize
{
   get{return this.AreaSize?.ToString(...);
}
```

Comment: see for this is my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42150774/why-linq-query-and-extension-dont-support-conversion-or-rounding-numbers