# Why LINQ Query and Extension don't support conversion or rounding numbers?

Tags: c#, linq

I try to round, format the numbers. But it doesn't seem to work in LINQ. I need to format, and round the numbers as the example below as your reference. Thank you for help. Exception I get.

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

The anonymous type is important to round non decimal number and format to comma separated:

B - 1000.5 the value must 1,001
C - 1000.2 the value must 1,000
D - 1080.588 the value must 1,081
E - 1010.45 the value must 1,000

Here's my code:

```
 var result = _context.DwPropertyMasters.Where(x => x.ShowMapPoint == "Y")
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    x.LandId,
                    a = x.Development == null || x.Development == "" ? x.Location : x.Development,
                    x.MapPointX,
                    x.MapPointY,
                    AreaSize = x.AreaSize ?? 0,
                    Premium = x.Premium ?? 0,
                    b = (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize) ?? 0,
                    c =
                    _context.DwPropertyDetails.Where(
                            z => (z.TransactionPrice > 0 || z.TransactionPrice != null) && z.LandId == x.LandId)
                        .GroupBy(z => z.LandId)
                        .Select(g =>
                            (g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.TransactionPrice)) /
                            (g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize) == 0 ? null : g.Sum(p => p.ActualSize)) ?? 0)
                        .FirstOrDefault(),
                    d =
                    ((x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2) == 0
                        ? 0
                        : (x.Premium == 0 ? null : x.Premium) * 100000000 / (x.AreaSize2 == 0 ? null : x.AreaSize2)) ??
                    0,
                    x.LandType,
                    e =
                    _context.DwPropertyDetails.Where(
                            y => (y.TransactionPrice > 0 || y.TransactionPrice != null) && y.LandId == x.LandId)
                        .Select(y => new
                        {
                            a = 1
                        }).Count()
                });
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
 var output = result.Select(x => new SearchViewModels
            {
                LandId = x.LandId,
                A = x.a,
                MapPointX = x.MapPointX,
                MapPointY = x.MapPointY,
                AreaSize = x.AreaSize,
                Premium = x.Premium,
                B = x.b,
                C = x.c,
                D = x.d,
                LandType = x.LandType,
                E = x.e
            }).ToArray();
```

This is the Class of ViewModel:

```
public class SearchViewModels
    {
        public long LandId { get; set; }
        public string A { get; set; }
        public string MapPointX { get; set; }
        public string MapPointY { get; set; }
        public long? AreaSize { get; set; }
        public long? Premium { get; set; }
        public long? B { get; set; }
        public long? C { get; set; }
        public long? D { get; set; }
        public string LandType { get; set; }
        public long? E { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: @T.S. how is that? I don't have an idea. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to capture precise decimal values, use the `decimal` (or `decimal?` if it must be nullable) data type, not `long` (you also should not use `float` or `double` as it sounds like you're dealing with numbers that require more precision).  Your B/C/D/E values should be `decimal?`s.

Comment: thank you for your advice. But I need to convert and format the number from the LINQ. But I don't have an idea. Can you help me.

Comment: You will never be able to set a decimal value to a long variable...  LINQ is probably rounding it for you when it sees the type.  Change the type of the variable and you should get your expected results.

Comment: I already was done that. But how can I format like this 1,001 from 1000.5? Directly LINQ or not directly but result is 1,001.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to be due to the default rounding mode for Decimal, which follows [IEEE Standard 754](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs471/Lec3/ieee754.pdf), section 4.1 which states (in part):

> An implementation of this standard shall provide round to nearest as the
>   default rounding mode. In this mode the representable value nearest to the
>   infinitely precise result shall be delivered; if the two nearest representable
>   values are equally near, the one with its least significant bit zero shall be
>   delivered.

This is confirmed at Microsoft's [`Math.Round` reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx).

What it boils down to is that half values will round towards even numbers.

Comment: do you have any solution. Just to format the numbers into comma separated example: from 1001 into 1,001