# Space as thousands separator for labels

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, custom-formatting

I have a label and im using binding and a FormatString as such:

```
<Label Text="{Binding buying_price , StringFormat='{0} EUR'}">
```

The label's text is bound to a double in my ViewModel, what im getting on the label is something like this: `10000 EUR`, what i want to get is `10 000 EUR`, and `12 501 005 EUR` for example (**without the trailing .00**).
I tried `StringFormat='{0:C2} EUR'` and `StringFormat='{0:N} EUR'` and `StringFormat='{0:n} EUR'` but non of them gave me a good result.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: you need to make a masked entry

https://www.xamarinhelp.com/masked-entry-in-xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not make it work in xaml, while when I use a convert and use string format in code behind, it works as excepted:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:thousandsSeparatorConverter x:Key="thousandsSeparator"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="{Binding date, Converter={StaticResource thousandsSeparator}}"  HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
    
</StackLayout>
```

And the `local:thousandsSeparatorConverter` :

```
public class thousandsSeparatorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string s = value as string;


        double number = double.Parse(s);

        // Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;

        // Displays the same value with a blank as the separator.
        nfi.NumberGroupSeparator = " ";
        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString("N0", nfi));

        string convertedNumber = number.ToString("N0", nfi);

        return convertedNumber;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `StringFormat='{}{0:#,##,#}'` depending on your culture you may need to change it in the code-behind if you get a result of `10,000 EUR` instead of `10 000 EUR`, in the former the `,` is a thousands separator not a comma.

You may want to take a look at the complete documentation for available [numeric format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings).

Related question helpful for culture: [How would I separate thousands with space in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17527847)